# Forgot user & pass on Debian laptop

Tags: linux, debian, login, password-recovery

The hard drive is encrypted and I do remember that password thankfully, so I can get to the login screen, but both the username and password I've forgotten. How do I determine the username and maybe reset the password?

Given these instructions https://www.vultr.com/docs/boot-into-single-user-mode-reset-root-password I cannot follow as there is no line that begins with `linux /boot/`.

Not sure whether I should try this https://serverfault.com/a/662362/454651 solution as the only line that begins with `linux` and ends with `ro  quiet` is a backup... ?

Is there anything that can be done from the command line accessible from the GRUB interface? Or what would be my best course of action?

Answer (score 4):

1. From GRUB menu, select **"Advanced mode"** and then choose your operating system.
2. Read the footer. As you'll see, you can **press "e"** to edit commands.
3. At the bottom of that commands - please use your arrow keys to go down -, after an echo, you'll see a line starting with **"linux" and following by /boot/vmlinuz.....**
4. At the end of that commands, you'll see **"ro quiet"**. Change "ro" to **"rw"**. This will change read-only file system to read-write mode.
5. After that, at the end of the same line, add **"init=/bin/bash"**. Note that your keyboard layout might be different at this screen.
6. Press **F10** to boot. You'll get a shell with a prompt something like **"root@(none):/#"**
7. Remount filesystem as rw mode: **mount -n -o remount,rw /**
8. Execute **passwd username**. Or **passwd root** if you need (Of course you need the root password. Otherwise you can change any user password with root access.)
9. Type **exec /sbin/init**

You're done.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to start in single user mode, if it exists on Debian (I am on Mac OS).  Looking on Google, it seems to exist indeed.

Comment: Or, if all else fails, boot with an installation/live disk, mount your disk and edit `/etc/shadow` to erase your password.